# Is there any way to automatically remove stamp from an image?

Tags: image-processing

Stamps in images have multiple colours (including red, blue, purple, etc.) and various shapes(including rectangle, ellipse, etc.).

I have found so many methods in there and all of them are suitable for a few kinds of images.

Comment: Your question is rather vague and unclear. It also lacks any context or sample images, and your own attempts at coding. Please click [edit] and try to improve it. Thank you.

Comment: No "semantic-unaware" method can do that. A stamp is not different from normal image content.

Comment: Without representative examples, we can't tell you more.